# Is it safe to replace a 11.25V laptop battery with 11.1V or 10.8V?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, voltage

I need a replacement battery for an older laptop that originally came with an 11.25V Li-ion battery (presumably 3 cells at 3.75V each).

The batteries I found online mostly have a nominal voltage of 11.1V or 10.8V (i.e. 3.7V or 3.6V per cell). I did some reading and this could be due to a different chemistry (e.g. cobalt vs. manganese) or marketing strategies that favor higher watt-hours.

Many battery vendors list these batteries as suitable replacements for my model, but I'm concerned about the safety and potential risks of using a battery with a lower voltage:

- Can these different voltage batteries (11.25V vs. 11.1V vs. 10.8V) be treated as equivalent/compatible for all practical purposes or will interchanging them cause a fire/explosion?
- More generally, what kind of discrepancies in voltage are considered acceptable? Are there authoritative sources or recognized guidelines I could use to determine compatibility?

Comment: Just to confirm - you have an older laptop that you still want to use running on battery.  It's not a desk-princess laptop; it actively gets moved about while running ?

Comment: It's OK for the laptop but maybe not so OK for the battery. 3.6V and 3.7V cell are usually charged to 4.2V and the charging circuit for a 3.75V cell may charge it to a bit higher, E.G. 4.25V. The battery cell in smartphones now are 3.85V nominal and can charge to 4.45V. If you care about safety, check the “charge terminate voltage”

Comment: @Criggie: yes, I still use it for some stuff.

Comment: @DejanGovc just confirming you *need* it on battery ?  It is eminently possible to run most  laptops with no batteries installed.

Comment: Get the battery closest in voltage to your existing one and try it.  You can ask the supplier to confirm that it will work before you buy it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, the ratio between 11.25 V and 11.1 V is only 1.3% ,and between 11.25 V and 10.8 V, 4%. The first is insignificant, well within tolerance of most electronic parts. The second implies a small drop in watt-hour capacity.

Second, modern chargers detect the **rate** of charge (as well as the *voltage* and *current*), and stop charging after the voltage has not changed for a period of time, protecting batteries, not only of differing *chemistries*, but of differing *age*, since the charge/voltage curve changes significantly with age. This means a modern charger is unlikely to overcharge a slightly lower voltage battery.

All electrochemical cells have a [*discharge curve*](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-204-how-do-lithium-batteries-work), i.e. the voltage drops with state of discharge. A cell that reads 4 VDC (12 V in a three-cell
pack) at *full* charge would read ~3.6 V (10.8 V for three) at 50% charge. A brand-new OEM battery, fully charged, would read ~12 V at full charge and ~11.25 V at ~80% charge (batteries are usually shipped partially charged, and it is often recommended that they be kept at 80% to extend the *service* life of the pack).

The batteries you've seen are unlikely to cause harm because of the voltage ratings, and might be rated at a different charge point, rather than having differing chemistries. That said, buy them from a reputable source, since a **defective** battery can certainly cause damage, or even fire!

Comment: “That said, buy them from a reputable source, since a defective battery can certainly cause damage, or even fire!” That’s the main thing. People try to cut corners with batteries but they are worth the money and foundational to laptops/notebooks.

Comment: It is generally **not** safe to charge a battery with a charger designed for a different voltage of battery. I agree the voltage difference won't matter while discharging, but laptops charge their batteries too. Incorrect charging of lithium-ion batteries can result in serious fires if the charger tries to cram more power into an already full battery. However, as stated in my answer, I'd trust the vendor to know what they're doing, unless there's a reason to think otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

These are most likely the same type or very similar. The voltage of a lithium-ion or lithium-polymer cell varies from about 4.2V when fully charged, down to 3.2V when fully discharged. There isn't "a" battery voltage, so we pick a place in the middle and call that "the" (nominal) voltage. Halfway between 3.2V and 4.2V is 3.7V. "Nominal voltage" literally means "the voltage written on the label."

If they chose a slightly different way to choose the voltage to write on the label, that doesn't mean the battery is different, just the label. However, it could be different. Li-Ion batteries are usually labeled as 3.7V nominal, and there could be a reason the manufacturer chose to write 3.75V instead. Halfway between 3.2V and 4.3V is 3.75V. Some manufacturers specify that you can charge up to 4.3V - whether the batteries are actually different, or whether it's just a marketing trick to write a higher capacity and shorter lifespan on the label, seems to be a matter of debate.

Ultimately, I'd trust the vendor's advice - if they seem trustworthy. If they're selling batteries that explode, they'd be in big trouble, even on a place like EBay. If many different vendors are giving the same advice, that makes it seem even more trustworthy.

Comment: The problematic case would be putting a cell with 4.2 V max charge voltage into a device that has a charger that goes up to 4.3 V. I'm under the impression that there are at least manufacturer quality control differences and probably also chemistry differences in the cells that are rated for higher charge voltage. But indeed if it is a complete battery meant for the laptop in question, it's unlikely to cause any problems.

Comment: @jpa it's also possible the laptop charges the battery up to 4.2V and the old battery was over-specced (maybe for longer lifespan)

Comment: +1: useful info, thanks.